# Program to calclulate slope using Python

Tags: python, class

I have to find slope by first making a class called point that takes as parameters x and y. Then i have to make a class called line which takes two points as its parameters. in the line class i have to make a function called get slope that calculates the slope and returns it. Here's what i've come up with

```
class Point:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
class Line:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.p1 = (x1,y1)
        self.p2 = (x2,y2)
        def getSlope(self):
            xvalues = (self.p2.x - self.p1.x)
            yvalues = (self.p2.y - self.p1.y)
            slope   =  yvalues/xvalues
            return slope
```

I cant get it to work

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get it to work"? We need to see how you are trying to use it and the exact error you are getting to be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Did your indentation get broken when you pasted the code here? The code won't even parse as written! Since indentation is significant in python, you really need to make sure the code looks here exactly as it looks in your source, otherwise we'll see different errors than you (the question is editable and there is instant preview when you type, so edit it until it shows correctly).

Answer (score 2):

You made some mistakes, first of all division in python (version less than 3) returns integer instead of floating point. you should import division from **future** package and second you haven't followed the indentation convention in python. following is the code that tested and works.

```
from __future__ import division
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class Line:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
    def getSlope(self):
        xvalues = (self.p2.x - self.p1.x)
        yvalues = (self.p2.y - self.p1.y)
        print self.p1.x
        slope   =  yvalues/xvalues
        return slope

p = Point(1,0);
p2 = Point(5,3);
l = Line(p,p2);
print(l.getSlope());
```